# How can i select div according to child div

Tags: css

```
<div> /*i want to select */
     <div>
           <div class="ui-message-error">
           </>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have a page something like that and i can not appoint class parent divs. So how can i select parent div if child of child of that div has *'ui-message-error'* class.

Comment: it's not possible in CSS3 yet

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that in CSS that is not possible, you can either do it the other way around and select the child of 'ui-message-error' or do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a direct child of a parent (for example the body) you could use `body > div { }`

If the div has a specific preceding element, for example:

```
<div id="specificDiv"> bla </div>
<div>
     <div>
           <div class="ui-message-error">
           </>
     </div>
</div>
```

You could use `#specificDiv + div { }`.

If you are looking for a way to select the div based on the class of the child, you'll need a Javascript solution

Comment: This will apply even if there is no such class ui-message-error....

Comment: Yes, that's true. Like said, if the TS is looking for a way to select it based on the childs class, it's impossible with just CSS. But maybe these alternatives gives him a workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.ui-message-error').parent().parent().css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it with CSS, but if you use jQuery it is possibele like this:

```
$(".ui-message-error").parent().parent().addClass('myparent');
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/fcrDX/

---

Your code could go like this:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<div> /*i want to select */
 <div>
       <div class="ui-message-error">
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".ui-message-error").parent().parent().addClass('myparent');
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.myparent{
    border:1px red solid;
}
```